# multiple watchers in Vue-Js

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, watch

How can we $watch multiple data properties by calling a single callback?
I tried something like this.

```
  data(){return{

    firstValue:[],
    secondValue:[],
    }

    },
    watch:{
    // I want to watch both `firstValue` and `secondValue` by a single function :function(){
    do somethings}
}
```

Comment: check this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42737034/vue-js-watch-multiple-properties-with-single-handler

Comment: Does this answer your question? [vue js watch multiple properties with single handler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42737034/vue-js-watch-multiple-properties-with-single-handler)

Comment: check this Github link once: https://github.com/vuejs/vue/issues/844