# How to watch for multiple values in Vue 3 script setup?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, events, vuejs3, watch

I have this watcher (inside `<script setup>`:

```
const form = reactive({
    body: '',
    image: ''
})

watch(() => form.image, () => {
    console.log(form.image)
})
```

which I want to expand to watch two reactive objects:

```
watch(() => (form.image, form.body), () => {
    console.log(form)
})
```

but this now only watches `form.body`. I've been trying to implement [this question's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42737034/vue-js-watch-multiple-properties-with-single-handler), but it doesn't seem to work like my watcher with new and old values. I want the watcher to trigger, when both values are updated.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I figured something out. It'll trigger when both values are true. You can put your own conditions in there.

```
const form = reactive({
    body: '',
    image: ''
})

watch(() => [form.image, form.body], () => {
    if (form.image && form.body) {
        console.log(form)
    }
})
```

<s>This seems to work for simple cases but when the code base gets large and using `global proxies` (like a reactive store) as well as using too many proxies, it can fail. I've tried it with 4 global proxies on a large project and it only triggered sometimes.</s>

Like @tao suggested in the comments, if you're working with nested objects, you have to use `{ deep: true }` in your watcher.

More about deep watchers in the [vue docs](https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/watchers.html#deep-watchers).

Comment: It works in all cases. If any of the watched array elements are non-primitive values (e.g: object, array, map) and you want to trigger the watch when their internal prop values change, you have to use `{ deep: true }` as third param. By default, `watch` is shallow, for performance.

Answer (score 7):

You need to call watch each time if you need multiple watchers:

```
watch(() => form.image, () => {
    console.log(form.image)
})
watch(() => form.body, () => {
    console.log(form.body)
})
```

if what you need is a watcher to watch the two then :

```
watch([() => form.image, () => form.body], 
([newImage, newBody], [prevImage, prevBody]) => {
    console.log(form.body, form.image)
})
```

if we take example on that answer : https://stackoverflow.com/a/45853349/8126784 from the question you linked

Answer (score 0):

This can be done with watchEffect it will check the reactivity:

```
watchEffect(() => {
  emit('update:selectedProduct', localSelectedProduct.value);
  emit('update:selectedOffer', localSelectedOffer.value);
});
```

Here's the vuejs docs: https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/watchers.html#watcheffect